# Make WSHttpBinding service connectable from outside

Tags: c#, wcf, wshttpbinding

I've created WCF service using WSHttpBinding:

```
ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
var httpLocation = "http://" + address + ":4041";
svh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None), httpLocation);
svh.Open();
```

and I've registered it in the system with

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:4041/ user=username
```

When I'm trying to connect to it from the localhost, the service works.

But when I place it on an other pc (with address='localhost' or address='ip-of-the-machine'), connection fails with following exception:

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.44.128:4041/ that could accept 
the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See 
InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Inner exception:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond 
after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host
has failed to respond 192.168.44.128:4041
```

I've tried adding the service to firewall, that didn't help.

What is the problem here?

**UPDATE**

Here are the relevant entrys from `netstat -ano`. The first one is the http endpoint, which is not connectable from outside, the second one is a net.tcp endpoint, which works fine:

```
TCP    [::]:4041              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
TCP    192.168.44.128:9939    0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2120
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify with "NETSTAT -ano" from a command-line prompt that your service is listening on the specified port. Once that's checked, try PING'ing your service box IP from the client box. If both succeed you are most likely looking at a firewall and/or network switch configuration issue.

Comment: Hey. Thanks to you, I've found the problem. Apparently, firewall was configured to only let requests through from my software, and the http listener was running in an other process (?). I've opened port 4041 for all processes, and that helped. Please, update the answer so I can mark it as correct